# Multiple query and filtering in data layer ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to perform multiple query and filtering in data layer.

Problem: I need to perform this on this layer as I have performance and cache issues when doing this on controller.js (using angularjs).

Overview: I need to display different tables per year level from the students database table. When the administrator click the button for 1st year it will display all 1st year students (other filtering and sorting are in table)

There are four html display tables: 1st year, 2nd year, 3rd year, and 4th year

Can I do that in the data layer? see code below:

```
        public IQueryable<RequestStudents> Get()
    {
        StudentsModelContainer context = DbContextFactory<StudentsModelContainer>.Create();
            var result = context.RequestStudentSet;
            return result;
    }
```

The above code will display all students

i have tried the below code but it only worked for first year and i cannot add the other three query

```
public IQueryable<RequestStudents> Get()
    {
        StudentsModelContainer context = DbContextFactory<StudentsModelContainer>.Create();
            var result = context.RequestSet.Where(x => x.YearLvl == 1);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why not add a parameter for the `YearLvl` - `public IQueryable<RequestStudents> Get(int yearLevel)`

Comment: Thanks will try that!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass parameter  to Get method, or you can overload Get method as below

```
public IQueryable<RequestStudents> Get()
{
    StudentsModelContainer context = DbContextFactory<StudentsModelContainer>.Create();
        var result = context.RequestSet.Where(x => x.YearLvl == 1);
    return result;
}

public IQueryable<RequestStudents> Get(int yearLevel)
{
    StudentsModelContainer context = DbContextFactory<StudentsModelContainer>.Create();
        var result = context.RequestSet.Where(x => x.YearLvl == yearLevel);
    return result;
}
```

To return FirstorDefault value you can update your method as below

```
public RequestStudents Get(int yearLevel)
    {
        StudentsModelContainer context = DbContextFactory<StudentsModelContainer>.Create();
        return context.RequestSet.Where(x => x.YearLvl == yearLevel).FirstOrDefault();            
    }
```

Comment: it's working thanks! but i need to also use "FirstOrDefault" to view the specific record. how can i do that here?

Comment: so it means that i need two methods? is it okay to have the same paramater?